# Need to perform a nested numeric sort (xslt 1.0)

Tags: xml, xslt

Below XML needs to be sorted on queueId per WorkingTemplate using XSLT 1.0

Reason for asking here: 
All examples seen till now are not having these kind of structures. 
Therefore I can't attach any working xslt for this.
Please help.

````
<Export>
    <WorkingTemplates>
        <WorkingTemplate label="MM_DR">
            <WorkingQueues>
                <WorkingQueue queueId="132" right="READ_WRITE"/>
                <WorkingQueue queueId="49" right="READ_WRITE"/>
                <WorkingQueue queueId="197" right="NO_ACCESS"/>
            </WorkingQueues>
        </WorkingTemplate>
        <WorkingTemplate label="FX_MA">
            <WorkingQueues>
                <WorkingQueue queueId="123" right="READ_WRITE"/>
                <WorkingQueue queueId="60" right="READ_WRITE"/>
                <WorkingQueue queueId="182" right="NO_ACCESS"/>
            </WorkingQueues>
        </WorkingTemplate>
    </WorkingTemplates>
</Export> ```


[![Situation before sort][1]][1]


[![Situation after sort][2]][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ojwu.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmyKf.png
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can try this** use **for-each**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="WorkingQueues">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each select="WorkingQueue">
                <xsl:sort select="@queueId" order="ascending" data-type="number"/>
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: It's working fine ! Thanks for the quick response !

Comment: Need to raise my reputation to 15 for doing the voting. Well work on that 